# PHP & MySQL Counting records with a timestamp of under 5 minutes ago

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 'users online' function on my C# program, every 3 minutes it will notify the server that the user is still here, when that happens it will preform a query to my database updating it with the users username and a PHP timestamp (`time();`) if the username is already in the database then it will just update the timestamp.

What I am trying todo is count the users online, I want todo this by counting the number of records which were last seen at maximum 5 minutes ago and then echo out that number. I am not sure how I could go about doing this so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you saving the date and time as an integer, when you should be saving it as a `DATETIME` type in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic query would be:

```
SELECT count(*) AS cnt
FROM yourtable
WHERE timestampfield >= DATE_SUB(now() INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

Comment: Thanks, would that work with the PHP timestamp? Or should I change to `DATETIME` as suggested above.

Comment: PHP timestamps are like unix time stamps - seconds since Jan 1/1970. MySQL date fields are different, but you can from_unixtime() and unix_timestamp() to convert between them.

Comment: Alright, will change it from `time();` to the MySQL `DATETIME` and then use that, thanks.

Comment: Looks like there's a comma missing: `DATE_SUB(now() INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)` should read `DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)`